# игнорирование дискорд бота

Tags: python, discord.py

почему я на текст бот в ветке поддержки ставлю реакцию галочки, бот не реагирует, также с крестиком.

```py
@bot.command(name='поддержка')
async def support(ctx):
    channels = [1124697436808556644, 2222222222222222, 3333333333333333, 4444444444444444]  # ID каналов, где можно использовать команду
    if ctx.channel.id not in channels:
        await ctx.send('Команду можно использовать только в определенных каналах.')
        return
    
    menu = discord.Embed(title='Выберите причину обращения в службу поддержки:', color=discord.Color.blue())
    menu.add_field(name='1. Вопросы по использованию', value='!вопросы', inline=False)
    menu.add_field(name='2. Проблемы со связью', value='!связь', inline=False)
    menu.add_field(name='3. Запрос на добавление функционала', value='!функционал', inline=False)
    menu.add_field(name='4. Другое', value='!другое', inline=False)
    
    message = await ctx.send(embed=menu)
    await message.add_reaction('1️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('2️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('3️⃣')
    await message.add_reaction('4️⃣')


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.member.bot:
        return
    channels = [bot.get_channel(1124697436808556644), bot.get_channel(2222222222222222), bot.get_channel(3333333333333333), bot.get_channel(4444444444444444)]
    if payload.channel_id not in channels:
        return
    
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    
    user = bot.get_user(payload.user_id)
    member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    
    if str(payload.emoji) == '1️⃣':
        reason = 'Вопросы по использованию'
    elif str(payload.emoji) == '2️⃣':
        reason = 'Проблемы со связью'
    elif str(payload.emoji) == '3️⃣':
        reason = 'Запрос на добавление функционала'
    elif str(payload.emoji) == '4️⃣':
        reason = 'Другое'
    else:
        return

    support_channel = bot.get_channel(1051576320187973672)  # ID канала, куда отправлять информацию о запросе на поддержку
    
    await support_channel.send(f'Участник: {member.name}#{member.discriminator}\nПричина обращения: {reason}')
    
    user_channel = await member.create_dm()
    await user_channel.send('Ваш запрос на поддержку был отправлен.')
    
    # Создание ветки доступа
    guild = message.guild
    admin_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='HELP STAFF')  # Замените 'Администраторы' на имя роли администраторов
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name='служба поддержки')  # Замените 'Ветки поддержки' на имя категории для веток поддержки
    if not category:
        category = await guild.create_category('Ветки поддержки')
    
    channel_name = f'поддержка-{member.name.lower()}'
    support_ticket_channel = await category.create_text_channel(channel_name, overwrites=overwrites)
    
    await support_ticket_channel.send(f'**Запрос на поддержку**\n\nУчастник: {member.mention}\nПричина обращения: {reason}')

    if str(payload.emoji) == '✅':
        user_id = int(message.content.split('\n')[0].split(': ')[1])
        user = bot.get_user(user_id)
        await user.send('Ваш запрос на поддержку был обработан.')
        await support_channel.send(f'Запрос на поддержку пользователя {user.mention} был обработан.')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await support_channel.delete()

    elif str(payload.emoji) == '❌':
        user_id = int(message.content.split('\n')[0].split(': ')[1])
        user = bot.get_user(user_id)
        await user.send('Ваш запрос на поддержку был отклонен.')
        await support_channel.send(f'Запрос на поддержку пользователя {user.mention} был отклонен.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в блоке кода выше вы проверяете возможные варианты выбранной реакции для `1️⃣`, `2️⃣`, `3️⃣` и `4️⃣` и если ни одна из них не подходит, то в блоке `else` выполняете завершение функции указывая инструкцию `return`.

```py
if str(payload.emoji) == '1️⃣':
    reason = 'Вопросы по использованию'
elif str(payload.emoji) == '2️⃣':
    reason = 'Проблемы со связью'
elif str(payload.emoji) == '3️⃣':
    reason = 'Запрос на добавление функционала'
elif str(payload.emoji) == '4️⃣':
    reason = 'Другое'
else:
    return
```

Если непонятно как это работает, то почитайте что такое `return` и почему после вызова этой инструкции дальнейший код функции не выполняется.